# Finding multiplicative order

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

Assume that $a$ has multiplicative order $l$ $\pmod m$. Let $k$ be given, find the multiplicative order of $a^k$ $\pmod m$.

So we have $a^l\equiv 1\pmod m$ and we're looking for the smallest $h$ such that $[a^k]^h\equiv 1\pmod m$.

The given proof is as follows:
Let $gcd(k,l)=d$ such that $k=k'd$ and $l=l'd$ and $gcd(k',l')=1$

$a^{kh}\equiv 1\pmod m$ $\iff$ $kh\equiv 0\pmod l$ $\iff dk'h\equiv 0\pmod {l'd}$ $\iff k'h\equiv 0\pmod {l'}$ and since $gcd(k',l')=1$, then $k'$ is invertible $\pmod {l'}$ which implies $h\equiv 0\pmod {l'}$

How can I justify the first and third equivalences? And does this mean that $h=\frac{ql}{d}$ for $q\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equivalence just results from the definition of the order of $l$: it's the positive generator of $\bigl\{n\in\mathbf Z\mid a^n\equiv 1\pmod m\bigr\}$.

For the 3rd equivalence, $dk'h$ is divisible by $l'd$ if and only if $k'h$ is divisible by $l'$, this should be clear.

Last question : yes, since $\dfrac ld=l'$.

Comment: Thank you! I understand the third equivalence now, it makes sense when you put it that way. I still don't get how the definiton of $l$ (smallest number such that $a^l$ is congruent to $1\pmod m$) allows us to say that $l|kh$.

Comment: Put it this way: $kh$ is a multiple of $l$. If not, the considering the (non-zero) remainder of the division of $kh$ by $l$,  we would have $a^r=1$  and $0<r<l$.

Comment: I see. So assuming $l$ does not divide $kh$, we can find a smaller, non-zero integer multiplicative order to $a\pmod m$ which is a contradiction since $l$ is already the multiplicative order. Is this correct?

Comment: Perfectly correct. Its also the argument to prove that in $\mathbf Z$ the ideal generated by $a$ and $b$ is the ideal generated by $\gcd(a,b)$.